# Database First: how should I model Parent references Child references Parent?

Tags: entity-framework

Apologies if my subject doesn't quite make sense but here's the issue:

In SQL Server I have:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
, Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Notes
(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,Employee_Id INT NOT NULL
, AddedByEmployee_Id INT NOT NULL
, Text VARCHAR(2000)
);

ALTER TABLE Notes
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_Notes
PRIMARY KEY (Id);

ALTER TABLE Notes
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Notes01
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_Id)
REFERENCES Employee(Id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Notes
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Notes02
FOREIGN KEY (AddedByEmployee_Id)
REFERENCES Employee(Id);
```

So, an employee can have one or more notes and each note is added by an employee.

I've modelled this in Entity Framework with this in my Note.cls:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Text { get; set; }

public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

public virtual Employee AddedByEmployee { get; set; }
```

And this is my Employee.cls:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public virtual List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
```

(I'm assuming that I only have to reference a notes collection from employee.cls once).

Currently, when I try to load the model I get a:

**Invalid column name 'Employee_Id1'.**

And it's running the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
[Extent1].[Employee_Id] AS [Employee_Id], 
[Extent1].[AddedByEmployee_Id] AS [AddedByEmployee_Id], 
**[Extent1].[Employee_Id1] AS [Employee_Id1]**
FROM [Notes] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([**Extent1].[Employee_Id1]** IS NOT NULL)
       AND (**[Extent1].[Employee_Id1]** = 684)
```

So it's expecting a column called Employee_Id1 but I'm not sure what is making it expect that. I suspect that there will be other issues with this after this one. If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your field names do not follow the default convention, you'll need to tell EF which fields should be used for those two Employee navigation properties.

```
[ForeignKey("Employee_Id")]
public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("AddedByEmployee_Id")]
public virtual Employee AddedByEmployee { get; set; }
```